# Crear una columna con datos de dos tablas distintas SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, subconsultas, sql-server-management

Bueno basicamente estoy haciendo una consulta en la cual estoy creando 3 columnas donde obtengo el nombre del supervisor de la misma tabla haciendo un left join y obteniendo su nombre y tuve el problema de que no todos los supervisores estaban en en esta misma tabla por lo que tuve que crear otra e insertar los que me faltaron, ahora el detalle es que no se como puedo puedo tomar esos valores en mi consulta ya que necesito obtener los datos de ambas tablas es decir, primero obtener los datos de mi misma tabla y en caso de que el supervisor no este y el registro quede como null buscar el supervisor en mi otra tabla y obtenerlo para que todos los campos que creé de supervisores tengan datos, intente con un ISNULL pero no todos los campos se llenaron y no se como puedo realizarlo... les dejo mi consulta para que puedan ver lo que he realizado y obtener sus opiniones de que puedo hacer:

```
with 
Prueba as(
select A.ID, 
       A.Puesto,
       A.supervisorID,
       A.name+' '+A.lastName as 'Empleado', 
       B.name+' '+B.lastName as 'SP 1', 
       C.name+' '+C.lastName as 'SP 2',
       D.name+' '+D.lastName as 'SP 3'
from [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] A 
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] B ON A.supervisorID= B.ID
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] C ON B.supervisorID= C.ID
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] D ON C.supervisorID= D.ID
)
select 
P.ID,
P.Empleado,
P.Puesto,
P.supervisorID,
IsNull([SP 1], E.fullname) As [SP 1],
IsNull([SP 2], F.fullname) As [SP 2],
IsNull([SP 3], G.fullname) As [SP 3]
from Prueba P
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] E ON P.supervisorID = E.ID
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] F ON E.supervisorID= F.ID
left join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] G ON F.supervisorID= G.ID
```

Comment: puedes agregar el resultado de la tabla final?

Comment: @MrDonPh0x Listo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema, es que una vez que no tienes un supervisor en la tabla de empleados, los siguientes no existirán.

Otro problema es que el diseño de las tablas está mal. Los supervisores por definición son un subconjunto de la tabla empleados y por lo tanto sus datos deberían de existir ahí y la tabla solo debería de contener una llave foránea junto con atributos que solo pertenezcan a los supervisores y no al resto de los empleados. Este problema no lo resolveremos aquí, pero es algo que debes considerar.

Para solucionar el primer problema, podemos consolidar ambas tablas en una consulta.

```
SELECT  ISNULL( E.ID, S.ID) AS ID,
        E.Puesto,
        ISNULL( E.SupervisorID, S.SupervisorID) AS SupervisorID,
        ISNULL( E.name + ' ' + E.lastName, S.FullName) AS FullName
FROM [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] E
FULL OUTER JOIN [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] S ON E.ID = S.ID;
```

Esto regresa a todos los empleados aunque no existan en la tabla supervisores y todos los supervisores aunque no existan en la tabla de empleados. Esa consulta la convertimos en un CTE. Así, podemos obtener algo como esto:

```
WITH cteEmpleadosSupervisores AS(
    SELECT  ISNULL( E.ID, S.ID) AS ID,
            E.Puesto,
            ISNULL( E.SupervisorID, S.SupervisorID) AS SupervisorID,
            ISNULL( E.name + ' ' + E.lastName, S.FullName) AS FullName
    FROM [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] E
    FULL OUTER JOIN [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] S ON E.ID = S.ID
)
SELECT  E.ID,
        E.Puesto,
        E.SupervisorID,
        E.FullName AS Empleado,
        S1.FullName AS [SP 1],
        S2.FullName AS [SP 2],
        S3.FullName AS [SP 3]
FROM      cteEmpleadosSupervisores E
LEFT JOIN cteEmpleadosSupervisores S1 ON E.SupervisorID  = S1.ID
LEFT JOIN cteEmpleadosSupervisores S2 ON S1.SupervisorID = S2.ID
LEFT JOIN cteEmpleadosSupervisores S3 ON S2.SupervisorID = S3.ID;
```

Como nota final, te quiero recomendar que los alias de la tabla tengan relación con las mismas. Eso facilitará la refactorización de las consultas y su lectura.

Comment: De la que me has salvado amigo, muchisimas gracias esto era lo que intentaba hacer pero no sabia como... te lo agradezco muchisimo :)

Answer (score -1):

Intenta algo así:

lo que hacemos es buscar primero los empleados.
después a sus supervisores directos
después los supervisores de esos supervisores
y después los supervisores de los otros supervisores.

entiendo que eso es lo que quieres hacer.

solo mi duda es la columna ID, si en la tabla de supervisores es su Id de empleado o un Id Propio de supervisor, de ser así, solo tendrías que cambiar el campo que relacionas.

y ya al final lo unes con un UNION.

Ojo, el UNION elimina duplicados, si quieres verlos, sería con UNION ALL.

```
;WITH
    Emp As (
select A.ID, 
       A.Puesto,
       A.supervisorID,
       A.name+' '+A.lastName as 'Empleado', 
from [basededatos].[dbo].[empleados] A ), --Nivel Base de Empleados
    Sup1 As (
    select 
        B.ID,
        B.Empleado,
        B.Puesto,
        B.supervisorID,
        B.fullname As [Nombre]
    from Emp A
    inner join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] B ON A.supervisorID = B.ID
    ),
    Sup2 As (
    select 
        B.ID,
        B.Empleado,
        B.Puesto,
        B.supervisorID,
        B.fullname As [Nombre]
    from Sup1 A
    inner join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] B ON A.supervisorID = B.ID
    ),
    Sup3 As (
    select 
        B.ID,
        B.Empleado,
        B.Puesto,
        B.supervisorID,
        B.fullname As [Nombre]
    from Sup2 A
    inner join [basededatos].[dbo].[tblsupervisores] B ON A.supervisorID = B.ID
    )

    select *
    from Sup1
    UNION
    select *
    from Sup2
    UNION
    select *
    from Sup3
```

Comment: Revisa de nuevo lo que está pidiendo. Tu consulta regresa algo distinto que además pierde la relación entre empleados y supervisores.